# Can t connect facebook on empathy

Tags: 14.04, empathy, facebook

I can' t connet facebook on empathy on Ubuntu 14.04
i open up empathy, it directs me to online accounts. I add my facebook accout.
Facebook is added but where it says applications connected to your facebook account there is shotwell and something else but not empathy ...
Also Enmpathy has the same message as in the begging :you have to set an account in order to see your contacts here.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to grant application access for Facebook account](/q/714573)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook have deprecated the API that was used by empathy. This is why this is  no longer possible. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/api-v1-deprecation

Facebook encourages you to use Facebook Messenger.